# Navbar li elements closer to each other

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way to make the li elements in the navbar closer to each other?

This is what I got now: http://www.bootply.com/JTr4LHykbe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just mention `width : auto` and it will work fine

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li {
width: auto;
}
```

If you mention any static width to `li` then if any of the text is too big then it will overflow the li tag.

to make the navbar center:

```
 .navbar {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  float: none;
  width: 50%; // adjust it as you want
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Even better this one! Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that my navbar isn't centered anymore?

Comment: you have mentioned 100% width for navbar that's why its not centered. reduce width and make margin: auto; it will align center